# What is the limit of $A^n$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & \alpha \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$?

Tags: matrices

For matrix $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1/2 & \alpha \\ 0 & 1/2 \end{bmatrix}$, determine 
$$
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} A^n
$$

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you at least found the first few powers of $A$?  That will give a clue.

Comment: You could start multiplying matrices and see some pattern. This is a very simple exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A = \dfrac{1}{2}I + \alpha N, \tag 1$

where

$N = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}; \tag 2$

note

$N^2 = 0; \tag 3$

since $NI = IN$, the binomial theorem applies to (1) and we have, *via* (3),

$A^k = \dfrac{1}{2^k}I + \dfrac{1}{2^{k - 1}}k\alpha N; \tag 4$

terms containing higher powers of $N$ vanish by virtue of (3).

Since

$A^k = \dfrac{1}{2^{k - 1}} \left (\dfrac{1}{2} I + k \alpha N \right ), \tag 5$

and $1/2^{k - 1}$ dominates $\alpha k$ for $k$ large, we see that

$A^k \to 0 \; \text{as} \; k \to \infty. \tag 6$
.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of alpha? If alpha is zero, which is a special case then we can take advantage of the following property.

[image]%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;a&0&space;%5C%5C&space;0&d&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5E%7Bn%7D" title="A^{n}=\begin{bmatrix} a&0 \\ 0&d \end{bmatrix}^{n}" />

[image]%5Cbegin%7Bbmatrix%7D&space;a%5E%7Bn%7D&0&space;%5C%5C&space;0&d%5E%7Bn%7D&space;%5Cend%7Bbmatrix%7D%5E%7B%7D" title="A^{n}=\begin{bmatrix} a^{n}&0 \\ 0&d^{n} \end{bmatrix}^{}" />

Since a and d here are equal to 1/2 then the matrix would eventuall go to zero.